# How many ways are there to select five bills from a cash box?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to select five bills from a cash box containing **Dollar (1 bills , 2 bills, 5 bills, 10 bills, 20 bills, 50 bills, and 100 bills)** ? Assume that the order in which the bills are chosen matters, that the bills of each denomination are indistinguishable, and that there are at least five bills of each type.

---

In this question, order matters. If ordered had not mattered, then it was a simple stars and bars problem.

How to solve when order matters? Moreover I am not getting the significance of "bills of each denomination are indistinguishable". How is it used here ?

I am getting **C(7,5) * 5^7 **.

Can anyone help here ?

Comment: How about $7^5$?

Comment: @barakmanos, Sir, If possible can you please answer ? Also, I am not getting the meaning of "bills of each denomination are indistinguishable".

Comment: $7$ options for the 1st bill $\times$ $7$ options for the 2nd bill $\times$ $7$ options for the 3rd bill $\times$ $7$ options for the 4th bill $\times$ $7$ options for the 5th bill.

Comment: If order *does* matter it's *much* easier than any stars and bars I've ever seen.  There are seven choices for each bill so the are $7^5$ ways to choose them.

Comment: @fleablood, why is  C(7,5) * 5^7 wrong here ? Can you correct me ?

Comment: @barakmanos, why is C(7,5) * 5^7 wrong here ? Can you correct me ?

Comment: Why is it right?????

Comment: Why would C (7,5)*5! be right?  I can't tell you why that is wrong, when I can't conceive of any reason at all that it would be right.  The first bill can be any one of 7 values.  So that is 7 choices.  The second bill can be one of 7 choises.  So that is 7x7 possible combinations.  And so on.  There are 5  bills.  Each of them can be one of 7 values.  So that is $7^5$ possibilities.  I don't see I can make it any simpler.

Comment: @barakmanos, Right I got it !! There are actually 5 positions and any position can be filled with either bill which will cause a different permutation. Thats why it is 7^5 , am i right now ?

Comment: @fleablood, My Bad !!! I got it now , thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 options for the first bill you pick.  There are 7 options for the second bill you pick, 7 for the third, etc.  You pick 5 bills, so the answer is $7 \times 7  \times 7  \times 7  \times 7 =7 ^5=16807$ ways to pick five bills.  I hope that this answers your question.